# Multiple belongs_to in a Phoenix App

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Here are the three models I currently have

**routine.ex**

```
defmodule DailyRoutine.Routine do
  use DailyRoutine.Web, :model

  schema "routines" do
    field :title, :string
    field :timeframe, :integer
    field :content, :string
    belongs_to :user, DailyRoutine.User
    has_many :comments, DailyRoutine.Comment 

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(title timeframe content)
  @optional_fields ~w()
  # rest of the code goes here
end
```

**user.ex**

```
defmodule DailyRoutine.User do
  use DailyRoutine.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :username, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string
    has_many :routines, DailyRoutine.Routine
    has_many :comments, DailyRoutine.Comment 

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(name username)
  @optional_fields ~w()
  # rest of the model code goes here    
end
```

**comment.ex**

```
defmodule DailyRoutine.Comment do
  use DailyRoutine.Web, :model

  schema "routines" do
    field :content, :string
    belongs_to :user, DailyRoutine.User
    belongs_to :routine, DailyRoutine.Routine

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(user_id routine_id content)
  @optional_fields ~w()
  #rest of the code goes here
end
```

Now the problem is I could not find a way in controller to do multiple `build_assoc` and chain them together to build a proper changeset.

Here is my controller:

**comment_controller.ex**

```
defmodule DailyRoutine.CommentController do
  use DailyRoutine.Web, :controller
  alias DailyRoutine.Comment

  def create(conn, %{"routine_id" => routine_id, "comment" => comment_params}, user) do
    routine = Repo.get!(DailyRoutine.Routine, routine_id) |> Repo.preload(:user)

    changeset = 
      user
      |> build_assoc(:comments)
      |> Repo.preload(:routine)
      |> Comment.changeset(comment_params)
      |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:routine, routine)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, comment} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Your comment was successfully posted!")
        |> redirect(to: routine_path(conn, :show, routine_id))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        redirect(conn, to: routine_path(conn, :show, routine_id))
    end
  end

  def action(conn, _) do
    apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn), [conn, conn.params, conn.assigns.current_user])
  end
end
```

What I have so far does not work, and I tried multiple things including building out a struct manually with specific relationship `id`'s etc.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply put the ids in manually in the struct and pass that to `Comment.changeset/2` for this instead of trying to use `build_assoc` since you already have `routine` and its `user` loaded:

```
changeset =
  %Comment{user_id: user.id, routine_id: routine_id}
  |> Comment.changeset(comment_params)
case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  ...
end
```

Since you have `routine_id` and `user_id` in the `@required_fields`, you can also put these ids in the params you pass to `Comment.changeset/2`:

```
comment_params =
  comment_params
  |> Map.put("user_id", user.id)
  |> Map.put("routine_id", routine_id)
changeset = Comment.changeset(%Comment{}, comment_params)
```

Comment: I tried something similar but for some reason I keep getting this error: `column "routine_id" of relation "routines" does not exist` even tough I have the relationship setup and columns in the db.

Comment: I actually just did `IEx` and the changeset is valid and all is well there but it looks like the problem is the `column_id relation` error I am getting

Comment: When do you get that error? After `Repo.insert!`? What happens if you try to insert the changeset from `iex`?

Comment: Just realized what was wrong: you have `schema "routines" do` in the `Comment` model.